# Click Button on One Sheet for Data on another Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a click button on "sheet1" and would like it to execute its code when clicked on "sheet2", where all the data is at. What is the recommended way to activate the other sheet?

I am new to vba and have read some posts about this in the past few days, but have not found a satisfying answer so far on how to implement the sheet change as simple as possible. I have seen things like:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(1, 1).Value = 1 
    Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(2,1).Value = 1
    ...
End Sub
```

, where I have to constantly redeclare the object's scope to "sheet2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `With` and `Activate` or `Select` will bring the sheet in focus.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   With  Worksheets("sheet2")
      .Cells(1, 1).Value = 1 
      .Cells(2,1).Value = 1
    ...

    '/Activate the sheet
     .Activate
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a difference in performance between `With Worksheets("sheet2")` and `Worksheets("sheet2").Activate` ?

Comment: you have just 2-3 cells to change then not really, but for larger numbers, definitely yes.

Comment: I have about 10000 rows of data in "sheet2", and the sub contains a lot of code. Is `With` then the recommended option?

Comment: I doubt there is any difference in performance. The only difference is that code will be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You could switch to `sheet2` and then execute any subsequent command without the need to explicitly mentioned `sheet2` like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Worksheets("sheet2").Activate    'Switch to sheet2

    Cells(1, 1).Value = 1    'this change will happen in sheet2
    Celss(2,1).Value = 1     'this too
    ...
End Sub
```